# simple code to read jpg files read retured 0 errno 0

Tags: c

I have simple code that reads a .jpg file

But my read returns 0 and errno is 0. I just prefer of use read with read syscall.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int fd=open("./a.jpg",O_RDONLY);
    int i=0;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",fd,errno,O_RDONLY);
    char buffer[1500];
    while(i<1500)
    {
        int valread=read(fd,&buffer[i],100);
        //printf("[valread = %d]\n",valread);
        i=i+valread;
    }

    i=0;
    while(i<1500)
    {
        printf("%x ",buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone point out whats wrong with above code.

Comment: When `read()` returns `0` it means you reached EOF.

Comment: Why 100 bytes read? When i > 1400 you'll get buffer overflow.

Comment: So if you're getting `0`, it means the file is smaller than 1500 bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane Since `i` is incrementing by 100 each time it reads 100 bytes, it will never be > 1400 until it gets to 1500 and the `while` condition fails. I know that `read()` is allowed to return less than 100 bytes, but in practice that never happens with plain files until you get to EOF.

Comment: @Barmar at first I overlooked the `i += 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop

```
while (i < 1500) {
    printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
    i++;
}
```

is not ideal, it will work fine if the buffer was correctly populated with `1500` bytes, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

I would suggest reading the entire file in one go, it's simpler and avoids the problems pointed out in the OP comments. You can then use the return value of `read` as the limit for the print loop, instead of the hardcoded `1500` value, *i.e.*:

```
int valread = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);

while (i < valread) {
    printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You didn't tell us what the value of `fd` is, if it's a positive integer it means the file was successfully opened, otherwise the `open` call failed. It can can also return `0`, but that is reserved for `stdin` so it shouldn't, unless you closed `stdin` elsewhere. You can use `perror` to further diagnose a possible problem.

If the `open` call indeed returns a valid file descriptor, then everything is fine and if the output is not what you expect that should mean the file doesn't contain the expected data.

Sample code with the suggested changes:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    
    int fd = open("./a.jpg", O_RDONLY);

    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int i = 0;
    char buffer[1500];

    int valread = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);

    while (i < valread) {
        printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```